# Understand bytes encoding for Gobs

Tags: go

and thank you in advance for your time!

I try to understand how gobs are encoded, following https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/gob.

I would like to understand how custom types/structure, ... are encoded (but this is not the question)

When writing some code to check bytes encoding, I found something strange.

For exemple in I try to encode the integer **7**, I get the following buffer **[3 4 0 2]** (the first byte is the length, the second the type and then the value). Here is my problem, checking the documentation the type of an int should be encoded using **2** not **4**, and its value should be obviously **0 1** and not **0 2**.

All my type IDs are multiplied by two (bool is 2 instead of 1, ...) and so are values...

I don't understand why, here is my simple code to reproduce:

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    var buf bytes.Buffer      
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buf) // Will write to buffer.
    // Encode (send) the value.
    err := enc.Encode(int(1))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("encode error:", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(buf.Bytes())
}
```

Am I missing something ?

Best!! and thank you in advance

EDIT:

Thank you all, I did an innattention error ... type ID are encoded using (uint(i) << 1) so for the type ID **2** is encoded as a 4 ..

Comment: 1. Where do you take the information of the bytes stream. 2. "[encoding 1] its value should be obviously 0 1 and not 0 2" on what do you base this? 1 is encoded as 1 one for unsigned integers. 3. TypeIDs are also encoded.

Comment: Sorry for missing that, and thank you for your answers!